# How to test properties of class using TDD?

Tags: objective-c, tdd, respondstoselector

Why when I use method `respondsToSelector:` or `instancesRespondToSelector:` at line 43 I cannot bypass STAssertTrue?

//My test case code

```
- (void)testApiClass {
    //Check object
    NSString* classKey = @"Api";
    id obj = NSClassFromString(classKey);
    STAssertNotNil(obj, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Model '%@' not found.", classKey]);
    //Check properties
    NSArray* properties =
    @[
        @"performSyncRequestWithUri::",
        @"performAsyncRequestWithUri:::",
    ];
    for (NSString* property in properties) {
        SEL propertySel = NSSelectorFromString(property);
        BOOL isRespondsToSel = [obj respondsToSelector:propertySel];
        STAssertTrue(isRespondsToSel, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Property '%@' not found on object of class name '%@'", property, [obj class]]);
    }    
}


@interface Api : NSObject

- (NSDictionary*)performSyncRequestWithUri:(NSString *)requestUri params:(NSDictionary *)params;
- (void)performAsyncRequestWithUri:(NSString *)requestUri params:(NSDictionary *)params completionHandler:(void (^)(NSDictionary *, NSError *))completionBlock;

@end
```

Comment: "at line 43" there are no line numbers

Comment: "performSyncRequestWithUri::" "performAsyncRequestWithUri:::" do you REALLY have methods named like this? I highly doubt it. By convention we don't usually create methods with empty keywords

Comment: Sorry line 43 in this case means next line: `BOOL isRespondsToSel = [obj respondsToSelector:propertySel];`

Comment: I am really have this methods. You can find interface bellow my post (and I have implementation)

Comment: This isn't TDD. What's the point of writing a complex test (with a for loop!) to prove that an object conforms to its interface? Xcode will tell you that without tests. Instead, write one simple, small test for one piece of functionality.

Comment: I agree. I initially misunderstood TDD. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods are called `performAsyncRequestWithUri:params:completionHandler:` and `performSyncRequestWithUri:params:`

Answer (score 2):

The string constants in your `properties` array don't match the selectors in your `Api` interface.

Also, neither of those selectors refers to a property.  A property has two selectors: a getter, like `stringValue`, which has no colons, and a setter, like `setStringValue:`, which has one colon and (usually) starts with `set`.

Instead of embedding your selectors in strings, make an array of selectors:

```
SEL selectors[] = {
    @selector(performSyncRequestWithUri:params:),
    @selector(performAsyncRequestWithUri:params:completionHandler:),
    NULL
};

for (size_t i = 0; selectors[i]; ++i) {
    SEL selector = selectors[i];
    BOOL respondsToSelector = [obj respondsToSelector:selector];
    STAssertTrue(respondsToSelector, [NSString stringWithFormat:
        @"Object %@ doesn't respond to selector %s",
        obj, sel_getName(selector)]);
}
```

The advantages here are that Xcode will autocomplete the selectors for you, and you can command-click the selectors to jump to their definitions.